# Manually set exposure for iOS camera in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, camera, avcapturesession

I understand that the camera in iOS automatically adjusts exposure continuously when capturing video and photos.

Questions:

How can I turn off the camera's automatic exposure?

In Swift code, how can I set the exposure for the camera to "zero" so that exposure is completely neutral to the surroundings and not compensating for light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the exposure mode by setting the "AVCaptureExposureMode" property. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388858-exposuremode).

```
var exposureMode: AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode { get set }
```

3 things you gotta take into consideration.

1) Check if the device actually supports this with "isExposureModeSupported"

2) You have to "lock for configuration" before adjusting the exposure. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1387810-lockforconfiguration).

3) The exposure is adjusted by setting an ISO and a duration. You can't just set it to "0"

[ISO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624649-iso):

> This property returns the sensor's sensitivity to light by means of a
>   gain value applied to the signal. Only exposure duration values
>   between minISO and maxISO are supported. Higher values will result in
>   noisier images. The property value can be read at any time, regardless
>   of exposure mode, but can only be set using the 
>   setExposureModeCustom(duration:iso:completionHandler:)  method.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a go. Do you happen to know what exactly the `{ get set }` means?

Comment: That you can either read the value of this property or set it yourself. If it didn't have the "set" it would mean that this is a read only property.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only min, current and max exposure values, then you can use the following:

**Swift 5**

```swift
    import AVFoundation

    enum Esposure {
        case min, normal, max
        
        func value(device: AVCaptureDevice) -> Float {
            switch self {
            case .min:
                return device.activeFormat.minISO
            case .normal:
                return AVCaptureDevice.currentISO
            case .max:
                return device.activeFormat.maxISO
            }
        }
    }

    func set(exposure: Esposure) {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else { return }
        if device.isExposureModeSupported(.custom) {
            do{
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.setExposureModeCustom(duration: AVCaptureDevice.currentExposureDuration, iso: exposure.value(device: device)) { (_) in
                    print("Done Esposure")
                }
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            }
            catch{
                print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    }
```